# Upload image on a web site using Java

Tags: java, image, upload

Is there any possibility to upload a file (for example: an image), to a site and to calculate the transfer rate?

I have some code that downloads an image from a specified url and calculates the transfer rate, using the `java.net.Url` class, something like:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //start time

    System.out.println("Connecting  site...\n");
    System.out.println("Downloading......");

    URL url = new URL("http://....");
    url.openConnection();
    InputStream reader = url.openStream();

    FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("D:/imagine.jpg");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[153600];
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0; 

    while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {  
       writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       buffer = new byte[153600];
       totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();//end of download

    long elapsedTime=(endTime-startTime)/1000;//from miliseconds in seconds 

    System.out.println("ElapsedTime is " +elapsedTime +" s");

    int memory=new Integer(totalBytesRead);

    double memoryFinal=memory * 0.0009765625; //file in Kb

    System.out.println("File size: " +memoryFinal +"Kb");

    System.out.println("Speed :" + memoryFinal/elapsedTime + "Kbps");
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
```

I need something easy and useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can - but it is not simple.

POSTing a file to a server is not implemented in plain java URLConnection, but you have to implements the protocol.

Or, You can use org.apache.commons.httpclient

http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the library [Apache FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

You can implement a progress bar too. See [this](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) .

Regards